# Выберите правильную форму сказуемого, подчеркните ее. Обоснуйте свой выбор

Tags: тип-сказуемого, выбор

(Произошло, произошли) два (удивительных, удивительные) события.
Говорят, что ряд негосударственных владельцев телекомпании (готов, готовы) предложить свои десять процентов в обмен на деньги.
Тогда (погибло, погибли) несколько рабочих.
Большинство людей (ответило, ответили) на этот вопрос
Большинство их (было, были) признанными экспертами.
Много людей (прошло, прошли) мимо памятника.
Сотни растений (взошло, взошли) на этих грядках.
Кроме основной гигантской трещины геофизикам (известно, известны) и несколько других.
Музей-квартира художника (закрыт, закрыта) на реставрацию.
Плащ-палатка (был, была) уже (сложен, сложена) и (упакован, упакована) в рюкзак.
«Аргументы и факты» уже неоднократно (поднимала, поднимали) эту проблему.
На стадионе (состоялся, состоялась) спектакль-феерия «Пусть всегда будет солнце!»

Comment: Здесь не решают домашние задания. Здесь помогают вам лучше понять русский язык. Предложите свою версию решения, и участники укажут на ваши ошибки